# How to call Controller action method from umbracoo

Tags: umbraco6

I am new to Umbracoo . I was trying to call Controller action method from umbracoo . I find the solution for how to render view but did not find any way to call action method of controller ..

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose first you would have to inherit your controller from **Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController or Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController**

have a look at:

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/mvc/surface-controllers

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/mvc/custom-controllers

Make sure that your view/partialView is created from umbraco backend as template so that it would have it's record save in database through unique id.
it would be hidden in your solution explorer first show all hidden items and the include in your project and start working on it.